# Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$(Implicit differentation + Quotient + Trig)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

**Question :**

> 1 Question:
> Find $\frac{d y}{d x}$ if $\sin \left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}$

I Applied the quotient rule simultaneously with implicit differentiation to be left with $\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{\cos (x) \cos (y)}{\cos ^{2}(y)-\sin (y) \sin (x)}$

I then thought I needed to replace $\cos (\mathrm{y})$ with $\frac{\sin x}{\sin \left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}$ but then found myself at a dead end whilst trying to replace $\sin (y),$ so i was wandering is this correct as the question does not specify the answer should be given in terms of $\mathrm{x} ?$ but again why would they provide me with $\sin \left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}$

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei3V8.png)

Comment: You can copy the LaTeX source code here, it should work with almost no changes. Use `>` at the start of a line to highlight the question.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the constraint $$\sin(x^2+y^2) = \frac{sin x }{\cos y} \tag 1$$ and want difference it implicitly, we can the constraint into $$\cos y \sin(x^2 + y^2)=\sin x $$ which is easier to difference. you get $$-\sin (x^2 + y^2)\sin y\, dy + \cos y \cos(x^2 + y^2)(2xdx + 2ydy) = \cos x dx. $$ separating the $dx$ and $dy$ and diving out  gives $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 
\frac{\cos x - 2x\cos y \cos(x^2 + y^2)}{2y\cos y \cos(x^2 + y^2)-\sin y\sin(x^2+y^2)} \text{ and } (1).$$

there are several equivalent answers here. you need to remember to carry the constraint $(1)$ along with any expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}.$

Comment: The derivative of $\cos y$ is $-\sin y dy$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, thanks. is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a formula of the form $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$. Implicit differentiation means that you consider $y$ as function of $x$ and differentiate to obtain
$$
f_x+f_y\,y'=g_x+g_y\,y',\text{ with }y'=\frac{dy}{dx}\text{ and } f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\text{ etc.}
$$
and rearranging 
$$
y'=-\frac{f_x-g_x}{f_y-g_y}
$$

---

For simplicity, rearrange your equation to be quotient-free.

Comment: Did you mean $y' = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$ and $f_x = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Comment: Yes, of course.